# Error while Downloading file to my local device from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from Amazon S3 bucket to my local device using the below code but I got an error saying "Unable to locate credentials"

Given below is the code I have written:

```
    import boto3
    import botocore

    BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket' 
    KEY = 'my_image_in_s3.jpg' 

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    try:
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
```

Could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please include the actual error? is there a line number listed? what line is it referring to?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to avoid the problems explained in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the session you created to download the file, you're using s3 client you created. If you want to use the client you need to specify credentials.

```
your_bucket.download_file('k.png', '/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

or

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=... , aws_secret_access_key=...)
s3.download_file('your_bucket','k.png','/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS use a shared credentials system for AWS CLI and all other AWS SDKs this way there is no risk of leaking your AWS credentials to some code repository, AWS security practices recommend to use a shared credentials file which is located usually on linux

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

this file contains an access key and secret key which is used by all sdk and aws cli the file the file can be created manually or automatically using this command

```
aws configure
```

it will ask few questions and create the credentials file for you, note that you need to create a user with appropiate permissions before accessing aws resources.

For more information click on the link below -:

[AWS cli configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)